# Построение сетки циклом из json

Tags: css, reactjs, map, nextjs, ionic

Я использую компоненты ionic. В json у меня содержится id, название, и размер. У меня не получается построить 5ю строку. Или как можно это реализовать с помощью css чтобы блоки вставали на свободное место.
Помогите составить цикл для построения следующей сетки:

```
  <IonGrid>
    <IonRow>
      <IonCol>1</IonCol>
    </IonRow>
    <IonRow>
      <IonCol>1</IonCol>
    </IonRow>
    <IonRow>
      <IonCol>1 / 2 </IonCol>
      <IonCol>1 / 2</IonCol>
    </IonRow>
    <IonRow>
      <IonCol>1 / 2</IonCol>
      <IonCol>1 / 2</IonCol>
    </IonRow>
    <IonRow>
      <IonCol>1 / 2</IonCol>
      <IonCol>
        <IonRow>1 / 2</IonRow>
        <IonRow>1 / 2</IonRow>
        <IonRow>1 / 2</IonRow>
      </IonCol>
    </IonRow>
  </IonGrid>
```

[image: вот такая структура]

Answer (score 0):

В документации по ионику есть такое:

> Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

В вашем коде - такое:

```
<IonGrid>
...
<IonRow>
  ...
  <IonCol>
    <IonRow>1 / 2</IonRow>
    <IonRow>1 / 2</IonRow>
    <IonRow>1 / 2</IonRow>
  </IonCol>
</IonRow>
```

Код `<IonRow>1 / 2</IonRow>` выглядит невалидным. Возможно, нужно добавить колонки внутри вложенных строк?

Comment: Ну это не критична ошибка. Вопрос остаётся открытым как составить цикл отрисовать это или css который будет заполнять пустое

Comment: [Сделал так](https://codepen.io/coolbick/pen/mdLBjEv) с помощью css, но это какое то извращение получается